# Authorize Adobe Reader to access a local file - Flutter app on Android

Tags: android, flutter, android-permissions

I am trying to open a PDF file with Adobe Acrobat Reader from a Flutter app (on Android).

The file I am trying to open is in the local storage of my Flutter app, so Adobe cannot access it. I am guessing that I have to specify somewhere that Adobe can read my file but I don't know where.

I would prefer not to copy the file in the downloads directory just to open it with Adobe.

I am using the [Open_file](https://pub.dev/packages/open_file) package.

```
OpenFile.open(filePath, type: "application/pdf");
```

Adobe open successfully but I get a toast saying `The file is inaccessible. Check the location or network and try again.`

Comment: How are you adding files to local storage? Using any specific library? If using Documents directory (on Android AppData directory.) it can't be accessible to any other apps...

Comment: Ok. I am storing my files in the relative directory of my app. I am downloading the files with Dio package: `await _dio.download(download_url, '/files/file.pdf')` so it is probably like you say.